# How to fill a C# sbyte array with a string (or other content)?

Tags: c#, string, list

I want to fill a sbyte[] with a string (and later also set specific values somewhere inside it at specific locations).

However, for a first test I want to add a string in it starting from the beginning. I tried:

```
var content = "Kronos Piano".ToCharArray();
var memory = new Memory.Memory(ref content);
```

where Memory's constructor expects a  'ref sbyte[] content' argument.

Also the content is only the length of the string converted.

In c I would use something like strcpy.
What is the best C# equivalent?

Comment: [`Convert.ToSByte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0hdkwd9(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht No, that *parses* a string that represents a number between -127 and +128, then converts that integer into the `SByte` datatype, which should throw an exception immediately: "FormatException: s does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (zero through nine).". OP on the other hand wants to represent `"Kronos Piano"` as a sequence of SByte's, apparently.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to interpret the *the content is only the length of the string converted* part. All that to say I think there are information missing or unclear (at least to me). And also wanting to translate C idioms into C# in often a bad idea ; it could be better IMO to describe what is the end goal to find idiomatic solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Encoding.ASCII` to get the string as an array of bytes. You can convert to SBytes as shown below.

```
string str = "Kronos Piano";
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);  // Gives an array of bytes

// To convert to SBytes
var sbytes = bytes.Select(b => Convert.ToSByte(b)).ToArray();
```